# Suggested Language for Web-Based Intranet/Database

Tags: database, forms, drupal, alfresco, intranet

Hate to ask a question this borderline generic, but I'm looking to build a web based program that combines our company intranet with a forms-based database.  I would be looking at Oracle's database product except that this definitely needs to be web based.

I'm currently investigating using Alfresco (java-based) as a repository, and some PHP engine for the front end.  Does anyone know of PHP issues when the task at hand becomes too involved (I'm an amateur, mind you), compared to Python, for example?  I would eventually like to be able to scale this project upward, even if I hired someone else to do it.

Pre-built modules would definitely help with the workload.  I know Drupal has many, but I've never perused compilations of modules for other languages.  I think the availability of modules may be the most important factor!

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco is great for managing content (e.g. documents or static html pages) in a collaborative manner. It has excellent tie-ins to the desktop with WebDav integration. Drupal is better for more dynamic web content and more flexible web pages.  Not quite sure what you mean by forms-based content.

With Drupal's CCK module (now mostly built into Drupal 7) and Views - you can create forms (as content types) for people to fill out and then present the results as either lists, tables, grids of nodes or almost any other filterable, list presentation you can think of using Views.

Every page in Drupal is really just a form that collects content to present in a particular way (e.g. the standard page is a Title field and a Body field), but a user profile is just another type of content form with a different set of fields.

Comment: As a healthcare company, we have massive documentation requirements.  I'm fearing that trying to use a basic forms engine would stir up trouble.  Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: For example, I'd eventually want to create an extension that would allow me to export a 20 page form with a hundred of fields into .pdf format.  I'd also eventually like to be able to generate forms for claim submissions.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco is currently getting better at Web Content Management (WCM). They recently rewrote the WCM feature set completely, and provide a [Quick Start](http://www2.alfresco.com/l/1234/2010-12-01/OOJYT) sample to, well, get you started quickly. Alfresco would provide you with a collaborative editing platform, with workflows, ACLs and extensive remoting capabilities (huge, extensible [REST API](http://admin%3aadmin@cmis.alfresco.com/service/index/uri/), WebDAV, [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)). You'll have configurable forms based content creation, plus a [platform](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Share) for your intranet.

The front end for Alfresco WCM would be than written using CMIS to retrieve content from Alfresco, APIs are [available](http://chemistry.apache.org/) for Java, Python and PHP.

Comment: Right.  Can you recommend any of the API?  The Alfresco Quick Start seems to be using javascript, which is why I steered away from it.  I don't want to lock myself out of the community modules I know many other languages have.

Comment: The Alfresco Quick Start makes use of both Java and Javascript APIs. Don't dismiss Javascript, in the recent years both communities and projects skyrocketed. On the minus side, I would use CMIS to fetch content out of the CMS, and there's AFAIK no good Javascript implementation (minor stuff has been done [here](https://github.com/jeremi/jquery-cmis)). If JS or Java are no-go, Python would be my choice, but that's mostly personal preference.